# GAE Ancestor Query Hack: is this a good practice?

Tags: java, python, entity-framework, google-app-engine, eventual-consistency

I stumbled on this feature of App Engine's Datastore that you don't actually have to have a persisted root entity to have strongly consistent behavior work with GAE. You can use a computed key to store and load child entities. **My question is: Is this a good practice or does this rely too much on an implementation quirk of the Datastore?**

Here's an example using Python. This idiom will work with Java, too, I'm sure.

Let's say you have a child entity:

```
CustomerReport(ndb.Model):
  foo=ndb.StringProperty
  bar=ndb.FloatProperty
  #...
```

CustomerReports are generated based on a real entity type, Customer. But you can save with strong consistency this report entity by computing an ancestor key for a non-existent parent entity like this:

```
ReportRoot(ndb.Model):
  pass
```

Like so:

```
CustomerReport(parent=ndb.Key(ReportRoot, customer.key.id()), ... ).put()
```

Which can be retrieved again by simply computing the key:

```
CustomerReport.query(ancestor=ndb.Key(ReportRoot, customer.key.id())).fetch()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a key as a parent that doesn't have a corresponding saved entity is perfectly fine. You don't even need to create a python class, just use the name as a string:

```
parent=ndb.Key('ReportRoot', some_id)
```

Your example, though, seems confused. What do you think you're gaining over just using the Customer's key as the Reports' parents?

Comment: I could use this technique to avoid locking the customer entity group when generating and reading reports.